# Windows Server 2016 can't read new environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I'm having a strange problem when installing my application on Windows Server 2016. (it runs fine on Server 2012 and Windows 7 to 10 clients).

FYI: I'm a software tester, not the programmer who wrote the code for the app or the installer. We deploy the app as .msi files, if that's important.

The installer for my application does three things: 
- it installs all neccessary files, by default into the folder C:\myapp. 
- it creates a directory C:\mydir\subdir and in that subdir it creates a file called info.text 
- it sets an environment variable called myvar with the content C:\mydir\subdir\info.text
(it can also create a desktop icon to launch the app, but that icon is not important)

The content of info.text is simple plain text: a path where the program can find its database. By default it would contain the path C:\myapp\dbsubdir

This works really well for some decades now and also works fine when installed on Windows 10.

On Windows Server 2016 I run the installer and manually check if C:\mydir\subdir\info.text and the variable myvar are present - and they are. The file info.text also contains the right content.

Then I start the app by clicking the desktop icon and get an error message. I asked my software developer and he said this error message can only be caused by one of two things: 
- the app can't find the environment variable myvar
- the app can't find the file C:\mydir\subdir\info.text

After I restart Windows the app starts as if the error had never happened.

On all other Windows Systems I can start the app directly after the installation is completed - my app doesn't require a restart of Windows.

I'm guessing that Windows Server 2016 needs a restart of some kind to be able to read newly created environment variables. But I found no proof for that thought or ideas how to get around that restart.

Is my guess true?

And if yes, is there a way around that restart?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've seen this specifically with Windows Server 2016.  The restart workaround is to logout and log back in.  That seems to force re-read of your environment variables set.